# How to do insert with a FK that is an object in Dapper?

Tags: .net, dapper

I have an object, `Ticket`, that has a property of type `User`. In the database, the `Ticket` table has a FK to the `User` table. Is there an easy way to pass the *ID* of the assigned user on the ticket into a query?

```
public class Ticket
{
    public int Id{get;}
    public User AssignedTo{get;set;}
}
public class User
{
    public int Id{get;}
}
public Ticket Save(Ticket newTicket)
{
    var sql = 
       @"
        Declare @localId int
        Insert into Ticket (AssignedTo)
        Values (@AssignedTo)

        Select @localId = CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int)

        Select
             Id
            ,AssignedTo
        From Ticket
        Where Id = @localId";
    var this.connection.Query<Ticket>(sql, newTicket);           
}
```

The above doesn't work because newTicket.AssignedTo is a `User` object, but what I need is to store the *ID* of the user.  Is there a supported way to do this with Dapper?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend to divide this functionality into two function. One is inserting data into **Ticket** table and return the last identity and second function is retrieve the record using that id.

**Note**: In your existing function you have passed parameter in wrong manner. You can do something like this with your existing function -

```
public Ticket Save(Ticket newTicket)
{
    string sql = string.Empty;
    sql = 
       @"
        Insert into Ticket (AssignedTo)
        Values (@AssignedTo);

        SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int);";

    var id = this.connection.Query<int>(sql, new { AssignedTo = newTicket.AssignedTo}).Single(); 

    sql = @"Select Id, AssignedTo
                From Ticket
                Where Id = @localId";
     return this.connection.Query<Ticket>(sql, new { localId = id }).Single();
}
```

But there is no need to execute select query again if i assume you want only 2 fields `Id` and `AssignedTo`. So in that case what you can do is assign newly generated id to your existing object `newTicket`, like this -

```
public Ticket Save(Ticket newTicket)
{
    string sql = string.Empty();
    sql = 
       @"
        Insert into Ticket (AssignedTo)
        Values (@AssignedTo);

        SELECT CAST(SCOPE_IDENTITY() as int);";

    var id = this.connection.Query<int>(sql, new { AssignedTo = newTicket.AssignedTo}).Single(); 

    // Assign the last identity value to the ID proerpty of newTicket object
    newTicket.Id = id;

    // Return the existing object
    return newTicket
}
```

good luck...